# Dragging multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I use Draggable from jQuery UI. Is it possible to drag many different containers in parallel?
I would like to grab just one div and move it. Other containers with the same name/argument should follow it and change their positions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but I could be wrong. I think doing that doesn't make much sense. Where would the items end up? However, if a container contains many items you can drag them all at once, but then you cannot drag the items separately. Basically you can only drag one "thing" at a time, whatever that is.

I have created nested draggable menu's where the parent drags all the childern along, and the chidren themselves are also individually draggable. It does work and looks like this:

[image]

Is that your intention?